# How do I detect an empty line from input or a file in Perl?

Tags: perl, while-loop

`while ($_ ne ' \n')` doesn't detect if the input is an empty line and loop indeterminately in while. Why?

Comment: Where does your `$_` come from?

Comment: What is an empty line? Is it empty when there are only whitespaces or tabulators? Or is "\n\n" an empty line?

Comment: Firstly, you're using \n in single quotes. It only has its special meaning in a double-quoted string. And secondly, you're checking for lines that contain a space followed by a newline - is that what you really want?

Answer (score 6):

Depends what you mean by "an empty line".

Does the line contain no characters other than the newline?

```
if ($_ eq "\n") # Note, \n only means newline in a double quoted string.
```

Or

```
if (/^$/)
```

Does the line only contain whitespace characters

```
if (/^\s*$/)
```

But that is easier if you invert the logic to say the line doesn't include any non-whitespace characters

```
if (! /\S/)
```

One of those should do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I used to use this regex to cross-platform match CRLF bytes:

```
/(\r?\n|\r\n?)+$/
```

so you can combine it with this one that matches empty lines: `/^\s*$/` in this way:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
 ...
open my $txtF,"$ARGV[0]";
for my $line (<$txtF>) {
  $line =~ s/(\r?\n|\r\n?)+$//; # strips all CRLF bytes at the end
  if ($line !~ /^\s*$/) { # now check if the line is not empty
    # do stuff
     ...
    # $line .= "\n"; if you need
    next;
  }
}
 ...
close $txtF;
 ...
```

Comment: FYI: `\R` matches any of `\r`, `\n` and `\r\n`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like shown below, inside the loop:

```
if ($_ =~/^$/) {
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are reading in the file. Probably the newline is being removed. You usually just read in the file as `while ( <> ) { ... }`.

Comment: @carol: You only read the first line. You have to include `<>` into the loop body.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
while(<>){
   if(/^$/){
                print "empty line";
        }else{
                print $_;
    }

}
```

It will open the file specified as arg0 on command line and print every line except the empty. <>  put every read line in $_ which is implicitly used in the if statement.